# How to find all installed apps including those which was installed using .sh

Tags: linux, installed-applications

I am looking for a way to identify on how to get a list all installed application including those applications on Linux which is not installed by any RPM package or YUM package.

I have installed Oracle Database using .sh and [My company application agent] one more application when I try to search for those application using

rpm -qa | grep 'application name' or using rpm -qa | sort |less

Or
yum list installed

Those applications were missing from the list. I am not sure why this is missing.

Could you please help me to find out this.

This is for Linux server.

```
rpm -qa
```

```
yum list installed
```

I am expecting the output of all installed application including those which are installed from .sh and .pkg or any third party application.

Comment: Related on serverfault: [Inventory or Audit Installed Linux Software](https://serverfault.com/questions/387111/inventory-or-audit-installed-linux-software)

Comment: It depends on how the application was installed. If you can share the .sh file, it may give a hint as to why `rpm` and `yum` is not able to find the application.